# UINavigationBar Item resizes after rotating

Tags: ios, xcode, navigationbar

I set the buttons of my NavigationBar this way:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addAcc = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Add"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(addNewAcc)];

UIBarButtonItem *delAcc = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
          initWithTitle:@"Del"                                            
          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
          target:self 
          action:@selector(DeleteButtonAction)];

NSArray *arrBtns = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:addAcc,delAcc, nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = arrBtns;
```

This works well but after rotating the device or changing the buttons, they get much longer.
How can I solve this?

Regards

Here is a screenshot:
Before rotating : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W3Hl.jpg
After rotating : https://i.stack.imgur.com/M27Hx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you should play with the property autoresizngmask of the buttons,
and autoriszessubViews .

check the refference :
[autorizing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask)